# Form dialog copies content of another form that it was called from

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I added code for a pop up window for login credentials. I used the microsoft documentation as a reference for the 'ShowDialog()' method for forms.

When the user clicks on the 'connect' button then he/she should be prompted in a pop-up to enter required credentials. The user should not be allowed to do anything else in the background untill the credentials are entered, hence the choice for a dialog.

However for some reason the content (some user control) of the original form is being copied to content the dialog. (see images)

```
private void Ss_ConnectionPressed(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    SSHCredentials credentials = new SSHCredentials();
    if (credentials.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ss.SetUser(credentials.GetUsername());
        ss.SetPassword(credentials.GetPassword());
    }
    else
    {
        ss.SetUser(null);
        ss.SetPassword(null);
    }
}
```

Here are some screenshots of what it looks like now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T9Q8.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE5Ls.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdBff.png

Comment: The code that you posted looks proper, perhaps the issue is elsewhere? What does the code file associated with SSHCredentials look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first screenshot I can see that you're main form class is named `Form` which is overwriting the default definition of the class `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. So the class `SSHCredentials` is inheriting traits from `Form` but should be instead inheriting from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.

The best solution is to name  your `Form.cs` to something more appropriate like `SensorForm.cs` and rename the class inside it to the same.